# How can you remove space between <H4> and a div with two inline-blocks?

Tags: html

```
<H4> This is the header</H4>
<div>
     <div style="display:inline-block">1st div</div>
     <div style="display:inline-block">2nd div</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5rgq4oh1/1/

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Are you asking about horizontal white space, vertical white space, or white space in the XML?

Comment: Both horizontal and vertical. The answer below has solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is caused by the bottom margin of the `H4` element.

To fix it, add this CSS:

```
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypenwq7c/)